How to create a TLS-CRYPT-V2 key with easy-rsa3?
I would like to create a TLS-CRYPT-V2 with easy-rsa3 to can use it with OpenVpn. I am following the documentation.
It says I can download and install Easy-TLS.
But i don't see the link to with the binaries, I can only find the source code.
Where could I find the binaries or how could I create the TLS-CRYPT-V2 for OpenVpn?
Thanks.

"But i don't see the link to with the binaries" There are no binaries, it's a set of shell scripts.
